# Tilde expansion broken

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

Today tilde expansion has broken on my Mac.

```
$ cd ~
-bash: cd: ~: No such file or directory
```

I use vi-mode on zsh along with oh-my-zsh and thought that could be causing the issue. But switching Terminal to use plain old bash didn’t fix it. Neither did switching to iterm2.

One weird issue is, when I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>“</kbd>, the cursor changes to a yellow block. This seems weird, but if I then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the command runs fine. I’ve verified this behaviour on both bash and zsh.

Having said that, this should interfere with `~` expansion anyway since the actual characters entered are correct.

I’ve tried Googling this problem, but couldn't find any mention of anyone else having problems with tilde expansion. Any advice would be appreciated.

This is a work machine running Ventura 13.5. I’m using Terminal v2.13 (447).

`echo $HOME` gives `/User/user` which looks correct

Comment: Why are you mentioning zsh, when you are doing this on bash?

Comment: If you explicitly type a (redundant) space after the tilde, does it work then?

Comment: Open a new Terminal session, then type `bash --norc`.  You'll get a new prompt and this will ensure no 3rd party "stuff" is loaded.  Next, type `ls ~` then press enter.  What's your output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you happen to be using the keyboard input source called US International PC, remove it and use US or ABC instead. US International PC turns those keys into accent makers.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-mac-mchlp1406/13.0/mac/13.0